Using REG_MATCH and REPLACESTR function in Informatica to replace a suffix character
We have a business scenario where the Source Data is getting populated as 'FIRST FINANCIAL SECURITIES OF AMERICA  I' where 'I' is getting populated as suffix. We need to remove the character 'I' from suffix and derive the data as 'FIRST FINANCIAL SECURITIES OF AMERICA' but when we use the below code in the expression transformation it is removing the character 'I' for all occurrence and gives the following out put string 'FRST FNANCAL SECURTES OF AMERCA'.
How can I achieve the above logic using REG_MATCH and REPLACESTR ?
**--parse suffix txt from last name**
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sI\s.*')  OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sI'),REPLACESTR(1,LAST_NAME,'I',''),
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sII\s.*')  OR REG_MATCH (LAST_NAME,'.*\sII'),REPLACESTR(1,LAST_NAME,'II',''),
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sIII\s.*')  OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sIII'),REPLACESTR(1,LAST_NAME,'III',''),
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sIV\s.*')  OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sIV'),REPLACESTR(1,LAST_NAME,'IV',''),
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sV\s.*')  OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sV'),REPLACESTR(1,LAST_NAME,'V',''),
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sJR\s.*')  OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sJR'),REPLACESTR(1,LAST_NAME,'JR',''),
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sJR.\s.*')  OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sJR.'),REPLACESTR(1,LAST_NAME,'JR.',''),
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sSR\s.*')  OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sSR'),REPLACESTR(1,LAST_NAME,'SR',''),
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sSR.\s.*')  OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\sSR.'),REPLACESTR(1,LAST_NAME,'SR.',''),
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\s3RD\s.*')  OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.*\s3RD'),REPLACESTR(1,LAST_NAME,'3RD',''),
LAST_NAME))))))))))


"it is removing the character 'I' for all occurrence" - according to the documentation, that's what REPLACESTR does - it replaces all occurrences it can find. You should probably rather do this whole thing using REG_REPLACE.

@CBroe Thank you for the solution,  Can you Please help me rewrite the code with a small example ?

Best guess - something like REG_REPLACE( LAST_NAME, 'I$', '') ...? $to anchor the pattern at the end, so that it only finds I if it is the last character.

Did you try something like:
IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME, '.*\\sI$'),  <- NOTE: no trailing asterix
REG_REPLACE(LAST_NAME, '\\sI$', ''),
SOURCE_COLUMN)

Your first REG_MATCH returns true if there is an I surrounded by spaces anywhere in the LAST_NAME. I don't think this is desired.
Then you're using REPLACESTR where I guess REG_REPLACE should be used. Review and let me know in case of further quesitons.

I have another requirement where we have 2 set of Data's like 'HOUSE ACCOUNT - WELLS FARGO - I' where the have to remove the suffix ' - I ' and another Data '3RD NAT-SEDALIA /INV SV/INVEST'  where I have to remove the prefix '3RD' currently I am Using the following code and its not working IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.\sI\s.')  OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.\sI'),REG_REPLACE(LAST_NAME,'I$','')   . IIF(REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.\sJR\s.')  OR REG_MATCH(LAST_NAME,'.\sJR'),REPLACESTR(1,LAST_NAME,'JR','') . Can you Please help me on this ? @Maciejg
